# Why does the magnetic field of an atom align with another significantly stronger magnetic field? I have trouble visualizing this

Tags: electromagnetism

What I’m currently visualizing is an electron orbiting a proton. The axis the electron rotates about is directly perpendicular to a strong magnetic field, or in other words, the magnetic field of the atom is directly perpendicular to a strong magnetic field.

From this visualization, I get that the atom doesn’t align itself with the magnetic field, but just spins faster and faster about the magnetic field vector

Let’s say there’s a magnetic field pointing upwards, and the electron’s axis of rotation is perpendicular to this. That means in the most upper part of the electron’s trajectory, the electron will experience a torque either to the left or right, but this torque will be “realized” 90 degrees “down the line,” and thus the “ring of rotation” will rotate about the magnetic field, but atom’s magnetic field and the strong magnetic field will never align.

Comment: ` but this torque will be “realized” 90 degrees “down the line,”` huh??

Comment: @SeñorO i was thinking something like gyroscopic precession is involved here. In a gyroscope, the force of gravity contributes to a torque trying to pull the gyroscope down, but this torque ends up actually being “realized” 90 degrees away, such that the gyroscope doesn’t fall down, and instead moves around in a circle

Comment: that's not what's going on here. The atom just has a magnetic moment due to the angular momentum of the electron's orbital (and spin). The electron is not actually orbiting and has no tangible angular velocity, just angular momentum. You get a torque according to $\tau = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$

Comment: [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)